# how to mock the dependencies of module in angular js using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm doing unit testing using jasmine, in my case module has some third party and some custom dependencies, i have tried some way to mock those dependencies but it doesn't works for me.

Below my code sample

**Module.js**

```
 var myApp = angular.module('mpapp', ['customservice', "xeditable",'ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize']);
```

**testmodule.js**

```
angular.mock.module('customservice', []);

angular.mock.module('xeditable', []);

angular.mock.module('ui.bootstrap', []);

angular.mock.module('ngSanitize', []);

module('myapp');
```

--- some required test cases here.

Like that i have tried to mock but it get error

"[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=eai.pages&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.9%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.bootstrap%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.9%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dui.bootstrap%250A%2520%2520%2520at%2520Anonymous%2520function%2520(file%253A%252F%252F%252Fd%253A%252Fvinoth%252Feai%252Fmetlife.eai-newlayout%252Fmetlife.eai%252Fangular%252Flib%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A229)%250A%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(file%253A%252F%252F%252Fd%253A"

So, give me any suggestion to resolve this issue. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i do it this way

```
  beforeEach(
    function(){
      module('myModule');

      inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_,_myService_){
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        myService= _myService_;

        //test code here

      }
    );
```

Comment: thanks, but i have tried same way like                   angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {  
           $mockservice = $injector.get('customservice');
           $mocktable = $injector.get('xeditable');

        }); this is also showing same error only